# Создание собственной модели пользователя в django_social_auth

Tags: python, django

Интересует, есть ли у кого-то примеры проектов на Django (`django\_social_auth`), в которых используется собственная модель для пользователя. Никак не могу разобраться как это работает вообще. Если есть, киньте ссылки, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С Django 1.5 появились [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-custom-user). Вот это, как я понимаю, первично для них. Тогда Вы заводите, по образу и подобию изкоробочной `User` свою модель, и пишете что-то в духе:

```
# settings.py
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myauth.models.User"
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = AUTH_USER_MODEL
...

# myauth/models.py
class User(django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    username = models.CharField(...)
    ...
...
```

Дальше Django (повторяюсь, 1.5+), видя `AUTH_USER_MODEL` само будет везде использовать вместо `d.c.a.m.User` эту `myauth.models.User`, про первое можно забыть.

Еще Вам оно может понадобиться только если у Вас своя (не `django.contrib.auth`), самодельная система аутентификации.

Или, если у Вас более старая версии Django — если Вы не использовали механизм профайлов (`User.get_profile`), а вместо него сделали свою модель, наследующую от `User`, и написали свой [backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-backends), возвращающий такую модель.

Тогда выставляете `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` указывать на свою модель, убеждаетесь, что у [менеджера модели](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#managers) есть метод `create_user` и, собственно, все. В наброске (не проверял код, могут быть опечатки) выглядит как-то так:

```
# myauth/models.py
...
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Менеджер, для модели пользователя (myauth.models.User).

    Реализует необходимый django_social_auth метод `create_user`.
    """
    def create_user(self, username, **fields):
        """Создает нового пользователя с заданным именем."""
        new_user = self.model(username=username, **fields)
        ...
        return new_user

class User(models.Model):
    """
    Полностью самодельная модель пользователя.
    """
    username = models.CharField(...)
    ...

    objects = UserManager()

    def is_anonymous(self): return False
    def is_authenticated(self): return True
    ...
...
```

В других случаях (в частности, если Вы используете `django.contrib.auth.models.User` без изменений), просто игнорируйте этот функционал.